# How to setup Espresso tests when using the Firebase-UI auth library

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, firebaseui, android-espresso-recorder

I have created the sign-in part of my app using the Firebase-ui auth solution (using com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.1). This library is great but I'm having trouble to setup my (Espresso) test cases.

In a test cases I would like to perform sign in using the mail provider (using a mail test account). Espresso does not seem to be able to do this: I'm not able to click on the "None of the above" button shown as the first screen after clicking "sign in with email".

Who has been able to perform a successful login on the Firebase-UI auth library using Espresso and how did you do this?

Below is the relevant test code (created using the new Espresso Recorder!)

```
ViewInteraction appCompatButton2 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.email_provider), withText("Sign in with email"),
                        withParent(withId(R.id.btn_holder)),
                        isDisplayed()));
        appCompatButton2.perform(click());

        ViewInteraction appCompatEditText = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.email),
                        withParent(withId(R.id.input_layout_email)),
                        isDisplayed()));
        appCompatEditText.perform(replaceText("a@a.aa"));

        ViewInteraction appCompatButton3 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.button_ok), withText("Next"), isDisplayed()));
        appCompatButton3.perform(click());

        ViewInteraction appCompatEditText2 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.password),
                        withParent(withId(R.id.password_layout)),
                        isDisplayed()));
        appCompatEditText2.perform(replaceText("aaaaaa"));

        ViewInteraction appCompatButton4 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.button_done), withText("Next"), isDisplayed()));
        appCompatButton4.perform(click());

        ViewInteraction imageButton = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.fab), isDisplayed()));
        imageButton.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Seems this is what he has gotten. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/200 The alert in question thrown by the SO actually

Comment: Yes, I solved this by using a recent Firebase-UI version and disabling the smartlock in feature.